# Openmp on Android

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I have some cute bc project... I need to make my code parallel and test it on Android. For testing I have a program which is called C4droid. Anyone can help me with this error when I compile :

> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'libgomp.spec':No such file or directory. Compilation terminated.

I've already have this spec file,but where it must be, I don't know. Is there any way to avoid this problem ?Is that not enough to add argument `-fopenmp`? Cause this app support omp.h

I'll show you gcc arguments:

```
cd (c4droid:GCCROOT)tmpdir
export TEMP=(c4droid:GCCROOT)tmpdir
(c4droid:GCCROOT)bin/(c4droid:PREFIX)-gcc (c4droid:SRC) -lm -ldl -llog -lz -I(c4droid:CURSRCDIR) -std=c99 -fno-diagnostics-show-caret -Wfatal-errors -fopenmp (c4droid:MODEARGS) -o (c4droid:BIN)
(c4droid:ERROUT)
```